# Do extension methods like `ToArray` and `ToList` operate by reference or by value?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a private dictionary or a list in my class. I want to return a readonly enumerator so that others can iterate over the list, but not have access to modify the items.

Instead of creating a wrapper class around the original, I'd like to return copies of the original items/elements. Will something like `original.ToList<Type>().GetEnumerator()` return a list with references to the original items, or a list with copies of the original items?

I should note that I also need indexing (i.e. accessing items by index, still not being able to modify them).

Comment: The answer to the title-question must be: Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods create a new instance of the collection, but the item references will still be to the old items. In other words, a consumer could not update your internal collection, but they could update the items themselves.

Assuming you have appropriate encapsulation around modifying the items, this approach will work, though it is a little memory-intensive for larger lists, since you need to allocate memory for each new item reference. That's one reason why returning a wrapper is often preferred: it reduces the extra memory required to a single instance of the wrapper class.

Comment: I have considered doing something like (psuedocode): `yield return newInstanceOfMyItem(valuesFromRealInstance)` in my `GetEnumerator`. Is that a valid approach?

Comment: @SimpleCoder It's valid, though probably overkill. If you want to ensure that consumers can change neither the list nor the items themselves, then you probably want to create a read-only wrapper for the items, and then return new instances of that class inste. It's a little clearer code-wise, and it's a lot clearer to consumers that they cannot update values on the returned items.

Comment: And for a `List<>` it's very easy, for there is a `.AsReadOnly()` method that creates the read-only wrapper. Of course, what dlev said about modifying the items themselves (if they are mutable objects) still applies.

Comment: perhaps rather than recreating your objects you could define a read only interface that they implement and return a collection of that interface instead of a collection of the implementation.

Comment: @dlev: I think my code snippet was trying to communicate what you suggested. A better way of showing it is: `yield return new MyClass(valuesFromInternalInstance)` in the `GetEnumerator`. Internal methods allow the internal instance to be manipulated, and public methods provide readonly access, in addition to the enumerator.

Answer (score 3):

`ToList()` and `Torray()` both work *by value*.  They simply copy the values from the original `IEnumerable<>` to the new container.

But the values being copied might very well be references.

Answer (score 2):

The straight call to

```
original.ToList<MyType>()
```

will create a "shallow" copy: the list will be new, but the objects will be the same.

If you would prefer a "deep" copy, you can use LINQ to duplicate your items before adding them to the list:

```
original.Select(item => new MyType(item)).ToList()
```

Assuming that your class has a constructor that takes an instance of itself and produces a copy, similar to a copy constructor of C++, this would produce a list of copies of your objects.

Comment: I would consider using the second call in my public `GetEnumerator` method, and then returning the iterator. I don't recall if this would produce lazy evaluation (i.e. not every single item is created at once), but I'm pretty sure it would; just like if I were to use `yield return new MyType(item)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, `ToList` would cause every element to be instantiated. Never mind. I guess I could return `original.Select(item => new MyType(item)).GetEnumerator()`, and then new items would only be created on demand.

Comment: @SimpleCoder This is correct, LINQ creates the elements of enumeration on demand, unless you call `ToList` or `ToArray`.

Comment: Ok, great. I think `return original.Select(item => new MyType(item)).GetEnumerator()` is the simplest way I can do this then.